Finding android.R.id.content view in jetpack compose activities
This is probably a stupid question but i have to ask it anyway.
In activities that are created solely by composables, is it still possible to use activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content) to find the activity's root view?
Appreciate the help and please dont kill me.
Edit:
This is how the code in ComponentActivity.setContent() looks like:
public fun ComponentActivity.setContent(
    parent: CompositionContext? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val existingComposeView = window.decorView
        .findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
        .getChildAt(0) as? ComposeView

    if (existingComposeView != null) with(existingComposeView) {
        setParentCompositionContext(parent)
        setContent(content)
    } else ComposeView(this).apply {
        // Set content and parent **before** setContentView
        // to have ComposeView create the composition on attach
        setParentCompositionContext(parent)
        setContent(content)
        // Set the view tree owners before setting the content view so that the inflation process
        // and attach listeners will see them already present
        setOwners()
        setContentView(this, DefaultActivityContentLayoutParams)
    }
}

So it seems that the root ComposeView is placed under window.decorView.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content), which means i can still use findViewById for it. Is this a correct assumption?

What did you experience after you tried?

@Leviathan That it can be used, but im not sure if i can generalize what i've tried

composable are not like view's hierarchy.

@Mahi Im aware. Im asking specifically about the activity root.

In Jetpack Compose, the UI is built using composable functions, and there is no direct equivalent of findViewById. Composables create and describe the UI hierarchy using declarative code, and the framework takes care of rendering and updating the UI based on the composable functions.
Instead of using findViewById(android.R.id.content), you can use the setContent method:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyComposable()
        }
    }
}


Im not sure how does that answer my question. Im aware that there is no equivalent to findViewById. But im asking specifically about findViewById for android.R.id.content which is the activity root. Is that still possible to use for the activity root only?

Im afraid not if you're Activity ui is a composable.

See my edited question with setContent code. It looks like that if existingComposeView exists then it is placed under android.R.id.content. And if its not then where is the root ComposeView placed under? Maybe still under the same android.R.id.content view?

The line window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content) retrieves the root view of the activity, which is a ViewGroup. This is where the ComposeView is placed. So, you can use findViewById to find this root view. But note that it is a decorView.
